# plpgsql Postgresql functions for calculating skewness and kurtosis

Tags: postgresql, statistics, plpgsql, skew, kurtosis

I was searching for Postgresql plpgsql functions to calculate "skewness" and "kurtosis" descriptive statistics functions, but I could not find any.
It would be great if someone can share such plpgsql functions here.
Thanks!

Comment: Install [PL/Python](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython.html) and use [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#summary-statistics)

Comment: Or try [stats_agg](https://github.com/ellisonch/PostgreSQL-Stats-Aggregate/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plpgsql function doing what I need, on github:
https://github.com/ellisonch/PostgreSQL-Stats-Aggregate/blob/master/pg_stats_aggregate.sql

Now I need equivalent of Excel's NORMSINV function as well :-)

Comment: I'm glad you've found it useful!  It might be better to link to the main page so people can see the installation and usage information: https://github.com/ellisonch/PostgreSQL-Stats-Aggregate/